# Nested Layout and route grouping

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

In my nextJs project, i want to have two layouts, one which is the landing with its own navbar, footer, hero, I also want to have the user layout where users can access all the main features like seetings, history, fundwallet and transfer. how do i achieve that. right now i am only able to achieve the user layout

i want a seperate layout for the landing page, and a common layout to return either the langing page or redirect the user to userlayout

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter, Poppins } from "next/font/google";

import "../globals.css";
import ThemeProvider from "src/provider/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider";
import GlobalProvider from "src/provider/GlobalProvider/GlobalProvider";
import UserLayout from "src/components/Layout/UserLayout";
// import MainLayout from "src/components/Layout/MainLayout";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'], weight: ['400', '500', '600', '700', '900'], style: ['normal'], variable: '--font-inter' });
const poppins = Poppins({ subsets: ['latin'], weight: ['400', '500', '600', '700', '900'], style: ['italic', 'normal'], variable: '--font-poppins' })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "ValuBox - User Dashboard",
  description: "A seamless way to buy utility bills, data and airtime.",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} ${poppins.className}`}>
        <GlobalProvider>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <UserLayout>
              {children}
            </UserLayout>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </GlobalProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

i expect to have USerLayout, then LangingPageLayout, such that in the RootLayout, if user session is not null and not expired, it will redirect to /user/dashboard else it will return the LandingPageLayou

Comment: What version of Next are you using? The app router in the newer versions of NextJS let you do layout management pretty easily.

Comment: i am using version 14.1.0

Comment: Then the [app router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) will be the most help.